# Include a file extension in ASP.NET Core MVC routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm porting a legacy application to ASP.NET Core and I'm trying to keep the URLs consistent. Ideally I need to include a "file extension" in the URL, e.g. `/Home/Index.ext` should route to the `Index` action on `HomeController`.

I've started with the standard web application template in Visual Studio and tried modifying the default route:

```cs
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}.ext/{id?}");
```

A request for `/Home/Index.ext` then gives the error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Index (WebApplication1)
WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy (WebApplication1)
WebApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Error (WebApplication1)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)
```

I can't see why it's not taking the action name from this URL to select the correct action. Is there some way I can change this route pattern to get it to match this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `IOutboundParameterTransformer` that's inside `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing`.

Simply create a transformer as follows (if you want the `.ext` extension):

```cs
public class AddExtensionTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
{
    public string TransformOutbound(object value)
        => value + ".ext";
}
```

Then you register it as a constraint (I used the name `addextension`):

```cs
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConstraintMap["addextension"] = typeof(AddExtensionTransformer);
});
```

And then in your route, you simply use `addextension` as a route constraint (using the `:` delimiter).

For the `default` route from your post, it will look like this:

```cs
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action:addextension=Index}/{id?}");
```

ASP.NET Core will now also automatically generate URLs like `/Home/Index.ext` whenever you tell it to generate an action URL.

So it not only parses them but also generates them (works both ways).

Answer (score -2):

You can then use an Attribute Route like this:-

```
[Route("Home/Index")]
public ActionResult Index() {... }
```

Comment: This does seem to work, but I was trying to avoid attribute routing as it would be a lot of repeated attributes on each action when the convention routing pattern would work fine otherwise. It might be that this is the best I can do though, but I’d still prefer a convention based approach.

Comment: Does not work for Asp.Net Core

Answer (score -2):

You can use URL Rewriting Middleware like below(`html` extension as a sample):

1.Custom a class containing `ReWriteRequests`

```
public class RewriteRules
{  
    public static void ReWriteRequests(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Path.Value.EndsWith(".html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Replace(".html", "");

        }
    }
}
```

2.Startup.cs:

Be sure use URL Rewriting Middleware before `app.UseStaticFiles();`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
                    .Add(RewriteRules.ReWriteRequests)
                    );

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
        
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Reference:

[URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0)